# Hls.js 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: node.js, cors, hls.js

I'm trying to set up a video streaming using HLS capabilities but I'm having trouble getting Hls.js to send my credential request to my server.

This is the code i have in my

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:[config.webAppUrl],
  methods:['GET','POST'],
  credentials: true
}))
```

As you can see i give access to my client to request to my server.

but when i want to use Hls.js to load some video from my server i got

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my code in client side :

```
this.hls.loadSource('http://localhost:8585/files/test/test.m3u8');
```

Please help me .

Comment: Are you getting the CORS error for the `m3u8` file request or for the `ts` chunk files?

Comment: @RamyBenAroya I'm getting this error for `m3u8` file request

Answer (score 0):

As Ramy mentioned, this is most likely not enabling cors.
Assuming you are using express.js

Run

`npm i --save cors`

Add this

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that i used cors 
but thanks for answering